# Changing value of an input

Tags: javascript, html

Alright, so I am having a little trouble here.. I am trying to create an option for users to embed my player how ever when I show code inside of a search box it corrupts the search box.

```
<h2> EMBED: </h2> 
<input class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" type="text" name="iframe" value="<iframe width="100%" height="175" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="http://www.example.com.net/embed.php?id=<?php echo strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $postID, 'Song-ID', '', '', '' ) ) ?>"></iframe>" readonly>
```

can someone please tell me how I can make this actually work?

Comment: You can't have an iframe *inside* an input element. Actually you can't have any element *inside* an input element. What effect are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @nnnnnn How can I make it so that it displays that iFrame inside of the search box then?...

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood. Is the idea to have the html source code for an iframe shown as the value so that the user can select it and copy/paste it into their own page?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes that is the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your opening and closing quotes are not matching as you assume they are. Use single quotes inside the string and wrap it all using double quote like so:

```
<h2> EMBED: </h2> 
<input class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" type="text" name="iframe" value="<iframe width='100%' height='175' frameborder='no' scrolling='no' src='http://www.example.com.net/embed.php?id=<?php echo strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $postID, 'Song-ID', '', '', '' ) ) ?>'></iframe>" readonly>
```